# Perl Invalid version format from Compat.pm

Tags: perl, build

I'm trying to publish a module, and am running into a lot of weird errors, the latest of which is as follows:

```
C:\Shared\John\Perl\unifdef+.0.5.1>build disttest
Creating Makefile.PL
Invalid version format (non-numeric data) at C:/perl/lib/Module/Build/Compat.pm
line 134.
```

The code at the specified line is:

```
if ( my $minimum_perl = $requires->{perl} ) {
    my $min_ver = version->new($minimum_perl)->numify;
    print {$fh} "require $min_ver;\n";
}
```

so it looks like `$minimum_perl` is corrupted.   I do have the line:

```
require 5.10.0;
```

In the code, but that should be OK according to the documentation I've read.

I tried upgrading various modules, and finally I tried a `cpan upgrade`, and upgraded my entire cpan, but I'm still getting the error.   Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I am running perl 5.24.1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out (sort of).  I'm posting an answer, as I assume others will run into the same problem, and hopefully this will help them.  My Build.PL script was a cut/paste/modify from an example on the web.  I had the following:

```
use 5.010000; # NOT 5.8.8 - needed by CPAN testers

use Module::Build;

my $builder = Module::Build->new( module_name => 'code::unifdef+'
       , license => 'perl'
       , requires => { perl => '>= 5.10.0' }   #hmm, this doesn't work...
       , dist_version => '0.005.001'
       , dist_author => 'John Ulvr <perldev@ulvr.com>'
       , dist_abstract => 'processes conditional parts of makefiles, c/c++ and kconfig files'
       , create_readme => 0
       , create_makefile_pl => 'traditional'
     );
$builder->create_build_script;  #generate Build
```

The `requires` line was causing the problem.   I'm not sure why though, as I've seen other similar examples on the web of the requires clause, so either everyone is wrong, or there's some sort of bug in in Compat.pm.   Removing the requires line fixes the problem (I have requires in the .pl file itself, so it should catch out-of-date issues).